# Android Play Upload Failed with: The maximum SDK version cannot be lower than the minimum SDK version

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

I am trying to upload my Android app to Google Play, however, on APK upload processing, I am getting the error:

```
The maximum SDK version cannot be lower than the minimum SDK version.
```

This sounds obvious, however, **nowhere** in my app is there a `maxSdkVersion` set. I have uploaded apk's in the past successfully, with those having only code differences.

Google-ing this error also yields *nothing*, so I'm completely at a loss here. Play does not seem to provide any more detail that that message.

**Has anyone seen this error on uploading an APK to Play before?** Or, does anyone know a way to get more detailed information on errors when uploading to Play?

I am using Android Studio 3.1.2, and building with Gradle 4.1

Comment: Open your manifest file in Android Studio and take a look at the "Merged Manifest" (tab choice at bottom of edit window). Look for `<uses-sdk` and see if a "maxSdkVersion" has been set. Also check any `<uses-permission` tags if a "maxSdkVersion" has been set.

Comment: Wow, there is actually. `<uses-sdk
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" 
        android:minSdkVersion="9" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`. How on earth did that get there? Could that have been added from a dependency?

Comment: Wow, indeed, clicking on the `uses-sdk ` line opens the manifest in AS, and I can see which dependency it comes from. Turns out, it was from a deprecated library. @Barns submit an answer, and I'll accept! Thanks for your help! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few places where one could find a value for `maxSdkVersion`: "build.gradle" and "AndroidManifest.xml"  files.

Open your manifest file in Android Studio and take a look at the "Merged Manifest" (tab choice at bottom of edit window). Look for `<uses-sdk` and see if a "maxSdkVersion" has been set.

Another place you might find a is under the tag `<uses-permission`. Check to see if a "maxSdkVersion" has been set.

If you need further information on these tags take a look at the Google Docs:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Comment: spot on. Thanks @Barns